# How to implement inheritance with closure in Javascript

Tags: inheritance, closures

I am being asked to implement JS inheritance with closure. I have the following code.

```
 function CreateUser(name, age) {
        let sharedFunctionalities = {
            sayName() {
                console.log(this.name);
            },
        };
        return function () {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.sharedFunctionalities = () => sharedFunctionalities;
        };
    }
    
    let user = new (CreateUser("jane", 22))();
    
    console.log(user); // {name: 'jane', age: 22, sharedFunctionalities: [Function (anonymous)]}
    
    user.sharedFunctionalities().sayName(); // undefined
```

I can't find a way to bind the this keyword in the sayName function so that it points to the current object instead of the sharedFunctionalities object. Could someone please help. I could do

```
user.sharedFunctionalities().sayName.call(user)
```

but this makes the code clunkier than it already is. Thanks.